# Can't install Windows 8 on new Hard Drive Sony Vaio

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, laptop, sony-vaio

I have a Sony E14127CN laptop. Its hard drive crashed, so I bought a new Hitachi Travelstar 7K500 hard disk as a replacement for the old Toshiba MQ01ABD075. But when I try to install Windows 8, it says " windows cannot be installed to this disk. this computers hardware may not support booting to this disk ensure that the disks controller is enabled in the computers bios menu. " I don't have any such options in the laptop's bios menu. **When I install Ubuntu on this laptop, it boots and works just fine.** Please provide a solution for installing windows on this laptop.

Comment: Maybe Windows installation needs "Sata Driver" for detecting the HDD, download and extract it to a pendrive and select the driver during installation: http://www.sony-asia.com/support/product/sve14127cn

Comment: Windows 7 and greater do not need a separate SATA driver.....in order to install it.

Comment: I tried putting the SATA Driver (http://www.sony-asia.com/support/download/576139/product/sve14127cn) on a pendrive and loading it in the windows installation but the installer says "No signed device drivers were found."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to connect you hdd to another PC (of same arc and CPU family), start the installation until first reboot, then plug the HHD back into your laptop, and finish the installation

Answer (score 0):

After selecting your language, click repair my computer>command prompt>diskpart>lis dis> select your disk (if it is 1 then sel dis 1, 0, sel dis 0)>clean
Reboot and try again. !!!this will delete all you data!!!

Comment: Already tried! Not working! :( In fact, I even tried installing it on new untouched hard disk. It didn't even install on that.

Comment: very weird, try to connect you hdd to another PC (of same arc and CPU family), start the installation until first reboot, then plug the HHD back into your laptop, and finish the installation.

Comment: I'll try this and let you know the results.

Comment: What I did was that I cloned the hard disk of my friends laptop which is a similar model with just larger screen and i3 instead of i5. Since this worked, your solution would also work. If you add that as a separate solution, I will accept it :)